# bash script to convert string value to json and then return json

Tags: bash, scripting

I am very new to bash scripting, please can someone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish my task?
I have a curl call which returns a string, which I want to convert  to json.

My curl statement -

```
curl --insecure -X POST 'https://url/api/IPAM/GetIP' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header -d '{"key1": "value1"}'
```

This curl statement returns a string ,for example: `10.100.100.100`

I want to fetch this string and return the output in json format:

```
{"IP":"10.100.100.100"}
```

I don't want to use jquery or python to do this because this entire script will be run by a wrapper that only understands bash.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jq` to process your IP string into a JSON string and package it into a JSON object of your choice.

```sh
ip="10.100.100.100"
jq --arg ip "$ip" -cn '{"IP":$ip}'
```

Result:

```json
{"IP":"10.100.100.100"}
```

Now if working with the result of your example curl POST request:

```sh
rawip_string=$(curl --insecure -X POST 'https://url/api/IPAM/GetIP' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header -d '{"key1": "value1"}')

jq --arg ip "$rawip_string" -cn '{"IP":$ip}'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to not rely on external tools like jq, you can get the output ip attribute that to a variable and concatenate it.

```
$ return=$(echo 10.100.100.100)
$ echo "{\"IP\":\"${return}\"}"
{"IP":"10.100.100.100"}
```

Comment: `printf '{"IP":"%s"}' "$return"` is arguably cleaner and easier to read/debug. Although it only work if `$return` contains no control character or double-quote that would need escaping to make it a proper JSON string.

Comment: Oops didn't see this comment)

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
printf '{"IP":"%s"}' "$(curl --insecure -X POST 'https://url/api/IPAM/GetIP' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header -d '{"key1": "value1"}')"
```